# Using a declared class as a function argument in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, express, canvas, node-canvas

I've declared a class `gly` that accesses a canvas made with node-canvas.

```
const width = 250;
const height = 250;
const canvas = createCanvas(height, width);
const gly = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

A separate function (outside that class) takes multiple arrays of [x,y] coordinates and should draw them onto the canvas. That function is initialized as

```
function drawShape(shapeClass, color, ...shapes) {
```

whereas `shapeclass` is `gly`.

I've already done this successfully without that function, but as I'm drawing so many shapes onto a canvas, I want to clean up the code by making that function draw the shapes whenever needed. The issue is that whenever `gly`'s class functions are called from within `function drawShape`, nothing happens. There aren't any errors, and `color` and `...shapes` pass perfectly fine into the function, but the function itself does nothing, leaving an empty space on the canvas.

Am I passing `gly` correctly into `drawShape`?

Comment: `gly` isn't a class, it's a variable.

Comment: All the same, why wouldn't its functions like gly.fill( ) and such not execute in drawShape( ) ?

Comment: Please show the complete code in a [mcve]. It shouldn't matter whether you refer to the drawing context via the variable `gly` or the variable `shapeClass`.

Comment: We can't help you unless you show us the actual running code that is causing you a problem and then ask a specific question about that code.  Right now, you have a theoretical question that isn't showing us the actual code.  Very hard for us to guess what is wrong.  We need to see a minimal, reproducible example of the code that illustrates the problem and a good, clear explanation of what you want help with in that code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - it had nothing to do with how I was using either the functions or the classes. Junk data found itself into an array and threw everything off.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).